# C++, ECS and Saving / Loading

Tags: c++, serialization, entity, components, deserialization

I have a program that employs an entity-component-system framework. Essentially this means that I have a collection of entities that have various components attached to them. Entities are actually just integer ID numbers, and components are attached to them by mapping the component to the specified ID number of the entity.

Now, I need to store collections of entities and the associated components to a file that can be modified later on, so basically I need a saving and loading functionality. However, being somewhat a newcomer to C++, I have hard time figuring out how to exactly do this.

Coming from Java and C#, my first choice would be to serialize the objects into, say, JSON, and then deserialize them when the JSON is loaded. However, C++ does not have any reflection features. So, the question is: how do I save and load C++ objects? I don't mean the actual file operations, I mean the way the objects and structs should be handled in order to preserve them between program launches.

Comment: There are many serialization libraries if you just look a little. Since, as you noted, C++ doesn't have reflection, none of the libraries works without your help, often in the form of you writing the function that does the actual serialization/deserialization of the data of each serializable structure (for example by letting you write members to a stream just like writing to e.g. `std::cout`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did find some libraries when I searched. The thing is, though, that I don't know how to construct the correct object based on the serialized data. Let's say there's a component `FooComponent` and another one called `BarComponent` - how do I know which one to construct without the reflection data?

Comment: It depends on the library you use. Some lets you register factory functions together with an identifier, and the serializer will put the identifier in the stream for the deserializer to read so it can call the correct factory function. Other libraries handles it yourself, which means you have to keep track of it yourself (maybe through a identifier-factory function mapping).

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing is to create [Persistent Objects](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/manual.xhtml#2.1/) in C++, and store the your data.

check out the following links:

C++ object persistence library similar to eternity

http://sourceforge.net/projects/litesql/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODB_(C%2B%2B)

http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184408893

http://tools.devshed.com/c/a/Web-Development/C-Programming-Persistence/

C++ doesn't support persistence directly (there are proposals for adding persistence and reflection to C++ in the future). Persistence support is not as trivial as it may seem at first. The size and memory layout of the same object may vary from one platform to another. Different byte ordering, or endian-ness, complicate matters even further. To make an object persistent, we have to reserve its state in a non-volatile storage device. ie: Write a persistent object to retain its state outside the scope of the program in which it was created.

Other Way, is to store the objects into an array, then push the array buffer to a file. 
The advantage are that the disk platters don't have waste time ramping up and also the writing can be performed contiguously.

You can increase the performance by using threads. Dump the objects to a buffer, once done trigger a thread to handle the output.

**Example:** 
The following code has not been compiled and is for illustrative purposes only.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::ofstream;
using std::fill;

#define MAX_DATA_LEN  1024 // Assuming max size of data be 1024

class stream_interface
{
    virtual void    load_from_buffer(const unsigned char *& buf_ptr) = 0;
    virtual size_t  size_on_stream(void) const = 0;
    virtual void    store_to_buffer(unsigned char *& buf_ptr) const = 0;
};

struct Component 
    : public stream_interface,
    data_length(MAX_DATA_LEN)
{
    unsigned int entity;
    std::string  data;
    const unsigned int  data_length;

    void load_from_buffer(const unsigned char *& buf_ptr)
    {
        entity = *((unsigned int *) buf_ptr);
        buf_ptr += sizeof(unsigned int);
        data = std::string((char *) buf_ptr);
        buf_ptr += data_length;
        return;
    }
    size_t size_on_stream(void) const
    {
        return sizeof(unsigned int) + data_length;
    }
    void store_to_buffer(unsigned char *& buf_ptr) const
    {
        *((unsigned int *) buf_ptr) = entity;
        buf_ptr += sizeof(unsigned int);
        std::fill(buf_ptr, 0, data_length);
        strncpy((char *) buf_ptr, data.c_str(), data_length);
        buf_ptr += data_length;
        return;
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    Component c1;
    c1.data = "Some Data";
    c1.entity = 5;
    ofstream    data_file("ComponentList.bin", std::ios::binary);

    // Determine size of buffer
    size_t  buffer_size = c1.size_on_stream();

    // Allocate the buffer
    unsigned char * buffer = new unsigned char [buffer_size];
    unsigned char * buf_ptr = buffer;

    // Write / store the object into the buffer.
    c1.store_to_buffer(buf_ptr);

    // Write the buffer to the file / stream.
    data_file.write((char *) buffer, buffer_size);

    data_file.close();
    delete [] buffer;
    return 0;
}
```