# profiler : enable/disable depend on value of a (global?) variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiler

I want to profile only at certain time-steps.  It is for game.

My game loop is like this (heavily simplified):-

```
for(int t=0;t<1000000;t++){
    doGameLoop();  // logic -> physic -> graphic -> sleep -> clear allocator ...
};
```

In Visual Studio, how to profile `doGameLoop()` e.g. only when `43<=t<=45`?
I want to profile while `-O2` turn on (release mode).

Now, I can only profile the whole program via
`(Top bar) > Debug > Performance Profiler > CPU Usage`.
It will show a graphical tree like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/10/29/profile-your-cpu-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2015/.

I don't mind a solution that make `t` a global variable, or insert some Microsoft-specific piece of code near `doGameLoop()`.
 I prefer to not change the other parts of my code.

(I have already searched for the solution for a few months.)

I heard that `QueryPerformanceCounter` may help, but I have no idea about it.

Comment: If you split your loop in 3 functions (0-25, 25-30, 30-1000000), profiler will inform you for each functions.

Comment: @Jarod42   Thank. I just tested it.  I made it calls  `doGameLoop1()`, `doGameLoop2()` and `doGameLoop3()`.   The `-O2` is very greedy, and the splitting is optimized out (probably become inline).  I am sad.

Comment: @Jarod42 Then, I also tried `#pragma optimize( "", off )` above the function that contain the condition `(0-25,....)`, in both `.h` and `.cpp`.  It has no  effect.

Comment: can you explain why you want to do this? What if you run only timesteps 25-30, but profile the whole program?

Comment: @tobi303 It is a physic simulation + some game logic, and I still don't implement serialization yet (load/save game).   Thus, I have to run from 0th time-step to observe a frame rate drop at 25-30th.  My program is deterministic.

Comment: Except if you use LTO, you may move the loop1, loop2, loop3 in separate translation units.

Comment: once you can store/load the state of the sim&game you can start&stop after any numbers of steps. I would do this first, instead of trying to find a workaround that helps for profiling only

Comment: @tobi303 Implementing load/save game is a very tedious work and hard to maintain.  I have read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046324/c-ecs-and-saving-loading , https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25963/how-do-i-create-a-save-file-for-a-c-game/25969#25969 ,http://www.byte56.com/2013/02/data-files-entities.html   , and https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-decide-text-vs-binary.   There seem to be only 2 approaches : binary (break after game update) and manual-field (extreme tedious).  If you know a better one, I would be glad.

Comment: no sorry I dont know a better one. Maybe I just dont see the problem, but I dont think it is tedious or hard to maintain, most of my objects can write to `ostream` and can be read from `istream` starting from day one, so if I would write something like this, I would be fine with writing simple text files for the start

Comment: @tobi303 Just curious. If a game designer need to add a new "map1:N" e.g. a new feature which a soldier unit in a strategy game has a magic to control some enemy missiles, you will have to serialize it, correct?  Is it a trivial task for you?  I want to check my mind-set. It is hard to find an experience game programmer to ask. :)

Comment: i am just a naive newbie that believes anything is possible and unless I understand the problem, I would say it is easy, yes ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 I split to 2 .cpp, then changed `Whole Program Optimization` from `Use link time code generation` to `No Whole program optimization` in every related project in the solution, the condition is still optimized out.  Hmm..